# How to use mysqli_stmt_bind_param() for multi params?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I tried this function and it works:

```
    $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($con);
    if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,"INSERT INTO `files` ( `Name`) VALUES (?) "))
    {
        // Bind parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$file_name);
        //mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$extension);
        // Execute query
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        // Bind result variables
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$district);
        // Fetch value
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

        printf("%s is in files %s",$file_name,$files);
    }
```

But how can I make it works for multiple parameters like this:

```
if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,"INSERT INTO `files` ( `FName`,`LName`) VALUES (?,?) "))
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#107200

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to extend your parameter binding like that:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$file_name,$lName);
```

`$lName` is the value you want to insert to the `LName` column.
The second "s" for the type parameter means that the `$lName` variable is also a string. Adapt this if it's not a string.